# Android. Поведение приложения после падения

Tags: android

В моем приложении после падения оно почему то не выгружается из памяти а открывает предыдущее окно. Как сделать так что бы при вылете оно не оставалось в памяти?

Answer (score 3):

При наличии более одного активити в стеке (коий пополняется при переходе от одного активити к другому) показывается предыдущее. Т.е. выполняется аналог вызова `finish()` для текущей активити. Или нажатия "назад".

Это стандартное и ожидаемое поведение - приложение при ошибке пытается восстановить работоспособность, вернувшись к работающему состоянию. Чтобы его изменить придётся пользоваться костылями.

1. Например запускать новую активити с флагом `NO_HISTORY` - так вы не сможете вернуться на предыдущее нажав назад, а только стартовав предыдущую активити интентом).
2. Можно переопределит стандартный приёмник ошибкок и в нём что-то сделать... Например завершив принудительно заранее сохранённые ссылки на запущенные активити. Но это уже совсем извращение.

Comment: Да это что то совсем не очень варианты. Лучше оставить стандартное поведение.

Comment: @FredGan, вот и я о том. Не очень понятно, почем у вас вообще возникло желание так сделать)

Comment: Поддерживаю чужое приложение, там видать предыдущее активити при возврате становится неработоспособным, нет половины данных. Вот и думал просто все вышибить

Comment: @FredGan, могу только посочувствовать)

Comment: Ну мне кажется, не сохраняет часть данных потому что там почти весь код в onCreate(), а при возврате к этому окну выполняется onResume() вроде, а там ничего нет.

Comment: @FredGan, вообще странно. Данные-то должны остаться, если их правильно хранят)

Comment: Ну значит мне не повезло)